# Парсер нескольких html страниц на qt

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x

Доброго дня! Делаю парсер для личных нужд и учусь программировать потихоньку.

Идея такая, вставляю из экселя список ссылок на сайты (они однообразны), ну например market.yandex.ru - есть 10-20 ссылок. Как в питоне обозначить этот список? я бы хотел его вводить в какой то texteditor, в окне Qt, далее нажимаю парсим - и программа загружает нужные странички.

.py парсер тут
http://pastebin.ru/RjDPll8T
Qt интерфейс для него тут:
http://pastebin.com/mG7Kxbtp

Comment: Конкретизируйте вопрос, в чем конкретно проблема? Если есть код который вы хотите показать, можно его в тексте вопроса вставлять отформатировав как код.

Comment: Здравствуйте, все коды вставил в pastebin.
конкретно: какой пример кода мне подойдет что бы парсер скачивал ни 1 страничку которая указана, а скачивал 10-ки страниц. Все адреса сайтов я планировал вставить в TextEditor элемент в Qt Интерфейсе программы. В итоге нужно что бы для каждой скаченной странички было свое отдельное пространство, для yandex.ru одно, для sait2.ru другое, и так далее. Далее с каждого сайта будут выбираться  <title> <img>  и их содержимое будет записываться в excel файл в формате заголовки (названия сайтов, и далее вниз по колонком  отфлитрованное  содержимое)

Comment: Ссылку `Qt` интерфейс не нужно показывать -- на алгоритм он не повлияет. И почему парсинг используя `Qt`? Для питона есть хорошие модули для парсинга, например `grab`, или связка `requests + lxml` (чем `grab` на самом деле и является)

Comment: Ну я полный новичек в этом деле. Qt мне нужен для того что бы был графический интерфейс, кнопки и места куда можно было вставлять список ссылок.  В будущем может определять какие параметры (тэги) выкачивать. А парсится тут все urllib кажется и requests. Про граб сегодня только узнал но не разобрался пока что как работает даже не ставил

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самый простой вариант: используйте `QPlainTextEdit` для хранения списка `url` – каждый url на своей строке. При нажатии на кнопку, получаете текст из редактора, разделяете его по символу перевода на следующую строку `'\n'` и обрабатываете url:

```
for url in self.ui.urls_text_edit.toPlainText().split('\n'):
    # Удаление пустых символов с края строки
    url = url.strip()

    # Если строка пустая
    if not url:
        continue

    seld.do_parse(url)
```

Для парсинга сайтов нужно что-то для скачивания страницы по `url` и что-то для вытаскивания информации со скаченной страницы, это может быть простой поиск по тексту, или поиск с помощью регулярных выражений, или разбор страницы как xml (html) и получения данных использую `sax`, `dom`, `css-селекторы`, или `xpath`.

`Css-селекторы` и `xpath` выражения по сути одно и тоже – ими описывается какие объекты из страницы html хотим получить.

Рекомендую, использовать xml-парсер с `xpath` запросами, вот пример скрипта для вытаскивания меток `ru.stackoverflow` с первой страницы. В `g.doc.select` описывается `xpath` выражения для получения ссылок на метки:

```
import grab
g = grab.Grab()

url = 'http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=name'
g.go(url)

for a in g.doc.select('//a[@class="post-tag"]'):
    tag = a.text()
    print(tag)
```

---

**Опишу наиболее частые инструменты.**

Для скачивания страниц: стандартный `urllib` или `requests`.

Для парсинга: `lxml`, `beautifulsoup` или `grab`.

---

Иногда, на некоторых сайтах, на которых активно используются скрипты, парсить описанным выше способом не получится, и тогда я использую движок `Webkit`, входящий в `Qt` как модуль `QWebKit`. Кстати, в нем поиск происходит с помощью `css-селекторов`, они по проще `xpath`. В этом примере заходим на страницу `ru.stackoverflow` и получаем текст с label:

```
from PySide.QtWebKit import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

view = QWebView()
view.show()
view.load('https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/login')

# Ждем пока прогрузится страница
loop = QEventLoop()
view.loadFinished.connect(loop.quit)
loop.exec_()

doc = view.page().mainFrame().documentElement()
print(doc.findFirst('label[for="email"]').toPlainText())
print(doc.findFirst('label[for="password"]').toPlainText())

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**Ссылки на некоторые мои скрипты для парсинга:**

- [Один из первых скриптов](https://github.com/gil9red/DownloadByPornSite/blob/master/DownloadByPornSite.py) для парсинга страницы с порно-сайта и
  получения ссылки на видео
- [Скрипт для вытаскивания](https://github.com/gil9red/hideme.ru-proxy-list) адресов прокси с сайта [hideme.ru](http://hideme.ru/)
- [Бот веб-игры](https://github.com/gil9red/moswar_bot), написанный на `python`/`Qt`. Парсинг и
  взаимодействие сделано через `QWebKit`.
- [Некоторый набор скриптов для парсинга](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/master/Grab), используя `grab`

Comment: Спасибо помогли пойти в правильном направлении!

Answer (score 1):

Для начинающих (как я), всем рекомендую посмотреть вот этот урок https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBDwd32Vwtg он весьма подробно объясняет как сделать парсер страниц (страницу директории и подстраницы), а так же выгрузить все это дело в Excel. Удобно так как все это в одном месте. Смотря обрывки уроков по парсингу от "ведущих" западных коллег - к сожалению собрать все в одну программу для новичков как я тяжело, без должной базы знаний.