# Отправка POST на kad arbitr при помощи python requests

Tags: python-3.x, парсер

Добрый день.
Пытаюсь получить данные из сайта http://kad.arbitr.ru/ при помощи python3 requests.
код:

```
import requests

payload = {
    'Sides': [{'Name': 'Ашан', 'Type': -1, 'ExactMatch': 'false'}],
    'Judges': [], "Courts":[], "CaseNumbers":[],
    "Page":1, "Count":25, "DateFrom" :"null", "DateTo": "null"
    }

    headers = {'User-Agent': 
       'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36',
       }

    r = requests.post("http://kad.arbitr.ru/Kad/SearchInstances",
              json=payload,
              headers=headers)
    print(r.text)
```

Итого выдает ошибку 403
Посоветуйте пожалуйста, что я делаю не верно.

Comment: Наверное, каких-тол заголовков или данных нехватает в запросе, вот сервер и отклонил его. 403: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#403

Comment: Полробовал сам, посмотрел запросы -- как-то сложно там сделано, наверное проще использовать какой-нибудь движок браузера

Comment: а что значит использовать движок браузера?

Comment: Браузеры умеют работать с html и js, в отличии от requests и подобных ему библиотек и на этим можно усложнить жизнь парсерам, добавив кучу js-скриптов и внутренних запросов на другие сайты, а так посмотрите мои ответы, я на подобные вопросы уже отвечал: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503041/ и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/500502

Comment: Спасибо, начал копать в этом направлении.

Comment: Не решили данную проблему? Столкнулся с ней же но возвращается ответом Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Answer (score 2):

Похоже проблема в том, что у них защита от кросдоменных запросов, т.е. ты не можешь откуда попало дергать их. Вот запрос с другого домена

```
$.post('http://kad.arbitr.ru/Kad/SearchInstances', {"Page":1,"Count":25,"Courts":[],"DateFrom":"2017-11-01T00:00:00","DateTo":"2017-11-05T23:59:59","Sides":[],"Judges":[],"CaseNumbers":[],"WithVKSInstances":false})
```

В ответ получаем:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://jquery.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

Как вариант запускать Headless Chrome через WebDriver, открывать там страничку kad.arbitr.ru, там открывать консоль разработчика и в консоли гонять запросы не чаще одного раза в минуту(иначе забанят IP). Сам так делать еще не пробовал.

Answer (score 0):

Для тех, кто ищет ответ по парсингу kad.arbitr.ru в 2022 году.
Мне надо было по работе получать информацию по арбитражным делам в качестве ответчика по ИНН организации. Защиту сайта получилось обойти только при помощи Selenium stealth эмулируя действия в браузере. Я начинающий... могу ошибаться, но пока так код работает.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_binary
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium_stealth import stealth
import time

def parse_arbitr(inn):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

    stealth(browser,
            languages=["en-US", "en"],
            vendor="Google Inc.",
            platform="Win32",
            webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
            renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
            fix_hairline=True,
            )

    browser.get('https://kad.arbitr.ru')  # Открываем сайт

    try:
        time.sleep(2)
        browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class="switcher-container"]').click()
        time.sleep(1)
        browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='radio'][value='1']").click()
        time.sleep(1)
        browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[placeholder="название, ИНН или ОГРН"]').send_keys(inn)
        time.sleep(1)
        browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[alt="Найти"]').click()
        time.sleep(5)

        path_link = str("//*[@class= 'b-cases']/tbody/tr/td/div/a")
        path_tab = str("//*[@class= 'b-cases']/tbody/tr")

        links = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, path_link)
        tabs = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, path_tab)

        len_link_tabs = len(links)

        urls = []
        delo = []
        for url in links:
            urls.append(url.get_attribute('href'))
        for d in tabs:
            delo.append(d.text)
        y = 1
        for i in range(0, len_link_tabs):
            delo.insert(y, urls[i])
            y +=2
        if delo == []:
            listt = ['Информация в картотеке арбитражных дел в качестве ответчика не найдена', 'https://kad.arbitr.ru/']
        else:
            listt = delo

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        listt = ['Информация в картотеке арбитражных дел не найдена', 'https://kad.arbitr.ru/']

    time.sleep(2)
    browser.close()

    return listt
```